# Can't connect UI to ViewController using Swift 2.0 in Xcode 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

So I am trying to connect some UI objects to my ViewController, but it doesn't seem like they want to connect to each other. Maybe this is something to do with having two ViewControllers?

Before you ask, I already tried to remove the other ViewController and worked to no avail.

Here is a video of my issue in progress. 
https://youtu.be/ha_6v92yJ6E

Comment: Choose that VC in storyboard, go to attribute inspector then change the class to that .swift file, then change `manual` to `auto` on top of the right side window

Comment: Probably you didn't set the class of that view controller to your class.

Comment: @MidhunMP hmm that seemed to fix it. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably your view controller class is not properly set. You need to go to **storyboard** select top yellow tab then go to **Utilities** on right then select **Identity Inspector** tab
[image: <code>Identity Inspector</code>]

Set your controller class name here for eg: `ViewController` in above image.
Hope this might help.